# Amazon fire 8 HD (2018) not detected on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kindle-fire

I have been trying to connect my Amazon Fire Tab 8 HD to Android Studio but nothing seems to be working.
I have downloaded and installed the latest Kindle USB driver from Amazon website, tried different USB cables that worked on my Android phone but it just does not work on my Fire 8 HD.

Debugging is switched on, USB Debugging is set to File Transfer, Kindle USB Driver is installed.

Am I missing something or is my Fire 8 HD faulty.

Any idea will be hepful. Thank you!